# A question about django and MyModel_meta.get_fields()

Tags: django, django-models

I have used the sentence `Scenario._meta.get_fields()` in order to get a list of all fields of my model class called Scenario.

I printed the list and I saw there are two types of fields:

Some of them are like:

```
<ManyToOneRel: sizigia.demand>
```

And others like:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField: parent>.
```

I want to create a list with only "django.models" fields like:

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField: parent>.
```

How can I do that with a simple sentence?

[image]

Comment: `foo = [field for field in MyModelKlass._meta.get_fields() if isinstance(field, IntegerField)]`

Comment: `from django.db.models import IntegerField`